# fetch egit Mylyn connector active tasks from another class

Tags: git, mylyn

I need to know if there is any task activated in the task List While adding files for Git staging?

### Edited:

The idea i am looking for is, while doing staging of files, I need to identify if there is an selected task by code from the Git StagingView class?

Any ideas?

[image: Mylyn functionality]
<sub>(source: [uploadimage.in](http://www.uploadimage.in/di/WCL8/Mylyn.png))</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see the active task without having the Task List view open, you can enable the task window trim. Go to Window/Preferences/Mylyn/Tasks and check "Show active task on window trim".

Other than that, Mylyn will fill in the commit message in the Git Staging view if it's empty every time a refresh happens on the repository and a task is active.

**Edit:** For programmatic access, have a look at the `org.eclipe.mylyn.tasks.ui` plug-in. The class `TasksUi` serves as an entry point, giving you access to all high-level task API classes. What you are looking for is found in `ITaskActivityManager`:

```
   ITaskActivityManager activityManager = TasksUi.getTaskActivityManager();
   ITask activeTask = activityManager.getActiveTask();
```